# How does the enumitem package place the labels?

Tags: lists, indentation, lengths, enumitem

In the following screenshot, I would like the 1st item A) in the inline mode to be at the same level of indentation of the labels A) to D) in the first list.

To do that I would like to know how the `enumitem` package places the labels.

[image]

Here is the code that I've used.

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{enumitem}

    \newlist{choices}{enumerate}{1}
    \setlist[choices]{label*=\Alph*)}
    \newcommand{\choice}{\item}

    \newcounter{choice}
    \renewcommand\thechoice{\Alph{choice}}
    \newcommand\choicelabel{\thechoice)}
    \newcommand\choicestarlabel{{\large $\square$}}

    \newenvironment{inlineChoices}{%
        \setcounter{choice}{0}%
            \def\choice{%
            \refstepcounter{choice}%
            \ifnum\value{choice}>1\relax
                \penalty -50\hskip 1em plus 1em\relax
            \else
                \hspace{\labelindent}% WRONG SPACING !!!
            \fi
            \choicelabel
            \nobreak\enskip
        }%
        \ifvmode\else\enskip\fi
        \ignorespaces
    }{}

\begin{document}

\noindent Bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla

\begin{choices}
    \choice $\dfrac{4}{7}$
    \choice $\dfrac{8}{24}$
    \choice $\dfrac{44}{121}$
    \choice $\dfrac{9}{11}$
\end{choices}

\noindent Bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla

\begin{inlineChoices}
    \choice $\dfrac{4}{7}$
    \choice $\dfrac{8}{24}$
    \choice $\dfrac{44}{121}$
    \choice $\dfrac{9}{11}$
\end{inlineChoices}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Not a solution to the spacing problem, but you should use the `[inline]` option for your inline list and define them with     `\newlist{inlinechoices}{enumerate*}{1}` and `\setlist[inlinechoices]{label*=\Alph*)}`. Then you don't need your `inlineChoices` environment.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion but it doesn't work...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about it not working. I've added an example in case others would like to do this.

Answer (score 9):

Your inline list gets the spacing you are giving it and the normal paragraph indentation, the code below ensures it starts with `\noindent` if at the start of a paragraph and then gets what I think is the right indentation, depending on the space you want between items.

```
    \newenvironment{inlineChoices}{%
\ifvmode\noindent\fi
\hspace*{\leftmargini}%
\hspace*{-\labelwidth}%
        \setcounter{choice}{0}%
            \def\choice{%
            \refstepcounter{choice}%
            \ifnum\value{choice}>1\relax
                \penalty -50\hskip 1em plus 1em\relax
            \else
\hspace*{\itemindent}%
            \fi
            \choicelabel
            \nobreak\enskip
        }%
        \ifvmode\else\enskip\fi
        \ignorespaces
    }{}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explications and the correction of the code.

Answer (score 7):

Using the `[inline]` option of `enumitem` makes doing this sort of list simpler. Since these lists are designed to be used in running text, you would need to wrap them in some sort of environment to deal with the spacing issues; I've ignored this in my example, however.  I've made the between item separation (`itemjoin`) `\qquad`. You can change this as needed. Based on your comments, I've also used the `parskip` package for setting a zero `parindent`.  Then I've used `leftmargin=*` and `align=left` for the regular `choices` list to make the labels align properly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{parskip} % for zero par indent the right way

\newlist{choices}{enumerate}{1}
\newlist{inlinechoices}{enumerate*}{1}
\setlist[inlinechoices]{label*={\Alph*)},itemjoin={\qquad}}
\setlist[choices]{label*={\Alph*)},leftmargin=*,align=left}
\newcommand{\choice}{\item}


\newcounter{choice}
\renewcommand\thechoice{\Alph{choice}}
\newcommand\choicelabel{\thechoice)}
\newcommand\choicestarlabel{{\large $\square$}}


\begin{document}

 Bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla

\begin{choices}
    \choice $\dfrac{4}{7}$
    \choice $\dfrac{8}{24}$\label{824}
    \choice $\dfrac{44}{121}$
    \choice $\dfrac{9}{11}$
\end{choices}

 Bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla As in \ref{824}
\bigskip

\begin{inlinechoices}
    \choice $\dfrac{4}{7}$
    \choice $\dfrac{8}{24}$
    \choice $\dfrac{44}{121}$\label{44}
    \choice $\dfrac{9}{11}$
\end{inlinechoices}
\bigskip

\noindent Bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla, bla As in \ref{44}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Your simpler solution for the inline list has one drawback : the spacing between consecutive items is too smal. Is the a way to fix this ? "If yes", I'll definitely use the inline mode of `enumitem`.

Comment: Yes, with the `itemjoin` parameter.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: Arghhh... I use `\setlength\parindent{0mm}` which destroys the good spacing for the inline list. How can I repair it ?

Comment: It's probably best to use the `parskip` package for a 0 `parskip`. I've updated my answer again. But now maybe is the time to read the `enumitem` documentation to see what options you have for setting the margins.  If you want the lists indented relative to the text, you will need to (i) adjust the `leftmargin` of the `choices` list, and (ii) wrap the `inlinechoices` in an environment that indents it an appropriate amount.

Comment: Nearly done... Sorry but is it possible to keep indentation for the lists ? You can kill me... :-)

Comment: I gave you instructions in my comment. (And read the documentation.)

Comment: Sorry, I've not seen your comment. I'll follow your instructions...